# Header not fixing at top of page

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, styles

On my website, I am currently creating at http://ubie-global.ubieportal.co.uk/ My header has a fixed CSS position.However, since I have made changes to the menu on my website. The header no longer is fixed at the top

Comment: And also my fixed menu, scrolls when it shouldn't!

Answer (score 0):

Put the header element before the "container-fluid" element:

```
body
  header
  container
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `page-wrap` class element

```
.page-wrap {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

To prevent page from scrolling when nav is open:

```
.page-wrap-menu {
    transform: translateX(-360px);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The only thing is I need the main site to scroll and the menu fixed